# TS | array[n] return undefined, array return correct

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a function, which push each key from Firebase to array for further usage in project.

```
// component.ts
let x = this.wordService.getWords();
let randWordList: any[] = new Array();
x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(word => {
  word.forEach(element => {
    randWordList.push(element.key);
 // here it works correct
    console.log(randWordList[0]);
// throw in console -L6VLfqZqj8AeYT_0jwt
  });
});
```

When I check in console whole array by name it outputs correct, but I have no access to random array member.

```
console.log(randWordList);
// outputs []
//         "0": -L6VLfqZqj8AeYT_0jwt
//          ...
//          length: 8
console.log(randWordList[3]);
// return undefined;
console.log(randWordList["3"]);
// return undefined;
```

Hope someone can help me understand what I doing wrong.

Comment: you're saying it works in the subscribe but not outside of it?

Comment: yes, inside of subscribe works, outside - return undefined.

Comment: You are shadowing the declaration of the list. Define the list out side of the subscribe and not inside of it.

Comment: excuse me for confusion. declared it twice, inside and outside, now corrected code, lasted only outside declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `randWordList` variable twice. This makes the subscribe work but then outside of the callback the variable retains it's original value of an empty list.

Change to:

```
// component.ts
public someFunction() {
  let x = this.wordService.getWords();
  let randWordList: any[] = new Array();
  x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(word => {
    word.forEach(element => {
      randWordList.push(element.key);
      console.log(randWordList[0]); // => "-L6VLfqZqj8AeYT_0jwt"
    });

    // use randWordList here since it is now populated.

  });

  console.log(randWordList[0]); // => undefined (subscribe callback has not been called) 
}
```

Comment: sorry, that was miscopied code for first time. now I corrected it with one outside declaration, but it didn't helped, as I checked up before post question

Comment: The you are probably accessing the array after the declaration of the callback but the callback has not completed so the list is still empty. Does this sound correct? Example: `subscribe(() => /* set list occurs async*/); console.log(randWordList[0]) /* => undefined */`. If this is what is happening you need to move the access to be inside of the subscribe callback.

Comment: If I understand correct, it means to move declaration inside subscribe?
If so - this perform to return undefined at outside logging, and causes errors on compilation state

Comment: 5 sec timeout help to get necessary logs. But this is not a problem with code. Thanks all for help figure out that it was problem with async request

Answer (score 1):

As @Teddy Sterne has commented, you have declared `randWordList` twice and are using the scoped `randWordList` within the `subscribe` when what you want to do is to use the outer declaration.

Just move the logging to outside of the `forEach` then you should be able to do what you want and access the array by index.